# Convert duplicate row to independant columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
ID,CUSTOMER_ID,ACC_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_ID,PACK_DESC,PACK_VALIDITY,PACK_NUMBER
1,ABCVRXJ,1027,1248,PackA,30,PACKA-XXXX
2,ABCVRXJ,1029,1249,PackC,32,PACKC-XXXX
3,XUVZ200,1028,12491,PackB,31,PACKB-XXXX
4,XUVZ200,1030,12421,PackD,33,PACKD-XXXX
```

I want the final dataframe to look something like:

```
ID,CUSTOMER_ID,ACC_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_ID,PACK_DESC,PACK_VALIDITY,PACK_NUMBER_1,PACK_NUMBER_2
1,ABCVRXJ,1027,1248,PackA,30,PACKA-XXXX,PACKC-XXXX
3,XUVZ200,1028,12491,PackB,31,PACKB-XXXX,PACKD-XXXX
```

Each CUSTOMER_ID who has opted for 2 packs should be converted into a single row, with both the PACK_NUMBERs being 2 new columns.

I tried:

```
df['index'] = df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').cumcount()
df_vchrNumber = df.pivot(index='CUSTOMER_ID', columns='index', values='PACK_NUMBER').rename(columns=lambda x: 'PACK_NUMBER_'+str(x + 1))
df_vchrNumber = df_vchrNumber.fillna('').reset_index()
```

but this returns,

```
CUSTOMER_ID,PACK_NUMBER_1,PACK_NUMBER_2
0123456789,PACKA-XXXX,PACKC-XXXX
9876543210,PACKB-XXXX,PACKD-XXXX
```

**but this is not the expected output as i'm not sure how to include the other columns **

Would somebody mind helping me out a bit?

Comment: Suggestion: take your current return, merge it with the original dataframe (using `pd.merge`) and remove duplicates (`drop_duplicates`). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need only first and last value of `PACK_NUMBER` use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for first values per groups and last value of `PACK_NUMBER` per groups:

```
s = (df.drop_duplicates('CUSTOMER_ID', keep='last')
       .set_index('CUSTOMER_ID')['PACK_NUMBER']
       .rename('PACK_NUMBER_2'))
df = (df.drop_duplicates('CUSTOMER_ID')
        .rename(columns={'PACK_NUMBER':'PACK_NUMBER_1'})
        .join(s, on='CUSTOMER_ID'))
print (df)
   ID CUSTOMER_ID  ACC_NUMBER  TRANSACTION_ID PACK_DESC  PACK_VALIDITY  \
0   1     ABCVRXJ        1027            1248     PackA             30   
2   3     XUVZ200        1028           12491     PackB             31   

  PACK_NUMBER_1 PACK_NUMBER_2  
0    PACKA-XXXX    PACKC-XXXX  
2    PACKB-XXXX    PACKD-XXXX
```

Your solution should be changed with remove duplicates and join `Series`:

```
df['index']=  df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').cumcount()
df_vchrNumber = (df.pivot(index='CUSTOMER_ID', columns='index', values='PACK_NUMBER')
                   .rename(columns=lambda x: 'PACK_NUMBER_'+str(x + 1)))

df=df.drop_duplicates('CUSTOMER_ID').drop('PACK_NUMBER',1).join(df_vchrNumber,on='CUSTOMER_ID')
```

And if need processes all columns:

```
df['index']=  df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index(['CUSTOMER_ID', 'index']).unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  CUSTOMER_ID  ID_1  ID_2  ACC_NUMBER_1  ACC_NUMBER_2  TRANSACTION_ID_1  \
0     ABCVRXJ     1     2          1027          1029              1248   
1     XUVZ200     3     4          1028          1030             12491   

   TRANSACTION_ID_2 PACK_DESC_1 PACK_DESC_2  PACK_VALIDITY_1  PACK_VALIDITY_2  \
0              1249       PackA       PackC               30               32   
1             12421       PackB       PackD               31               33   

  PACK_NUMBER_1 PACK_NUMBER_2  
0    PACKA-XXXX    PACKC-XXXX  
1    PACKB-XXXX    PACKD-XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` with `agg` to select the `first` row of the group. Then groupby again and get the last row, finally merge the two dataframes together to get your wanted output:

```
a = df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID', as_index=False).agg('first')

b = df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID', as_index=False).agg({'PACK_NUMBER':'last'})

df_final = a.merge(b, on='CUSTOMER_ID', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
```

---

```
  CUSTOMER_ID  ID  ACC_NUMBER  TRANSACTION_ID PACK_DESC  PACK_VALIDITY PACK_NUMBER_1 PACK_NUMBER_2
0     ABCVRXJ   1        1027            1248     PackA             30    PACKA-XXXX    PACKC-XXXX
1     XUVZ200   3        1028           12491     PackB             31    PACKB-XXXX    PACKD-XXXX
```